# Move to bottom of page after fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looping through each element that has a class of `.fadeIn`, and then what I would like to do is move to the bottom of the page (since this goes top down). It should always be at the bottom of the page.

The following code doesn't work:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function ($) {
    var delay = 900
    $( ".fadein" ).hide();
    $( ".fadein" ).each(function (index) {
      $( this ).delay( index * delay ).fadeIn( "slow" );
      $( "html, body" ).scrollTop( $( document ).height() );
    });
});
```

Comment: Show us your html as well please.

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz It's available as a jsfiddle, here: http://jsfiddle.net/VtUme/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want is the page to automatically scroll to each item as it fades in.

Try changing it to:

```
 $( ".fadein" ).each(function (index) {
    $(this).delay( index * delay ).fadeIn( "slow" );
    $( "html, body" ).scrollTop( $(this).offset().top );
})
```

$(this).offset().top -  will return the position of the element from the top of the page.

Comment: Ah! Adding it as a callback to the fadeIn method seemed to work. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. 
I also had a little play with your code and made this http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/VtUme/2/
<3 jQuery